# Can HTML make a textarea "readonly" in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, textarea, readonly

I have a form that uses javascript to populate a textarea with some text.  The user should be able to copy the text, and I've used the code below to make the textarea readonly.

```
<textarea readonly id="newList" name="newList" placeholder="When you click 
 the button below, your list appears here.  Copy and paste it into your 
 new document. Use CTRL-A to quickly select all items."></textarea>
```

Works great in Chrome, but in IE10 the textarea is STILL not readonly, and when a user clicks in it the text that they want to copy disappears, replaced by the cursor.  It has nothing to do with my javascript -- I removed the "script" line from my HTML and this still happens.

Is there an easy way to make a textarea readonly in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying that exact code in IE10 and the textarea is read-only, however when you click on it the placeholder text disappears. I believe this is normal behaviour for IE though. Are you putting the text that needs to be copied in the placeholder attribute? If so that is the problem.

The textarea with the text that needs to be copied should look like this:

```
<textarea readonly id="newList" name="newList">Text that needs to be copied...</textarea>
```

It can also have the placeholder attribute added, but that text specified in the placeholder attribute will not be displayed any more.

Also note that if you use the disabled attribute, you won't be able to copy the text in the textarea.

Comment: I'm not putting it in the placeholder attribute.  I'm using var foo =createTextNode(newList.join("\n")); then appendChild to the textarea.  Does that inadvertently place it into the placeholder attribute?

Comment: This is absolutely crazy. You'd think that IE10 would be able to handle a simple "readonly" HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable your textarea, however this not only prevents it being editable but also means it isn't sent on submit - so it depends how you want to use it if this is a good idea.

You could add an onFocus() event to your text area to move the user off the textarea if they click into it.

Comment: disabling the text area means the user wouldn't be able to select and copy the content...